# Two definitions of genus for circle graphs

Tags: graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

In the (very nice) article of Goldstein and Turner untitled *Applications of Topological Graph Theory to Group Theory*, the following definitions can be found:

**Definitions:** A *circle graph* is a pair $(G,S)$ where $G$ is a trivalent graph and $S$ a Hamiltonian cycle. (Topologically, a circle graph consists of a circle together with a finite number of arcs whose end points are disjoint on the circle.)

An *embedding* of a circle graph is defined as a piecewise linear embedding $f : (G,S) \to (M,\partial M)$ where $M$ is obtained from a closed 2-manifold $\hat{M}$ by removing an open 2-cell.

Finally, the *oriented genus* $\gamma^0(G,S)$ of $(G,S)$ is the genus of the oriented manifold $\hat{M}$ of minimal genus so that there exists an embedding of $(G,S)$ into $(M, \partial M)$

If $g(G,S)$ denotes the usual [genus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)#Graph_theory) of the associated graph, the inequality $g(G,S) \leq \gamma^0(G,S)$ is clear. Does the equality hold?

Comment: It's not really relevant for your question, but this terminology is not good, because there's already a different and more standard definition for a circle graph: it's the intersection graph of a collection of chords of a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found that $\gamma^0(G,S)$ and $g(G,S)$ can be quite different. For example, let $(G,S)$ be the following circle graph:

[image]

Using properties proved in Goldstein and Turner's article, $\gamma^0(G,S)=3$ (see the picture below for a visual justification). However, it is clear that $g(G,S)=0$. In fact, the example generalizes easily to get, for all $n \geq 1$, a circle graph $(G,S)$ satisfying $\gamma^0(G,S)=n$ but $g(G,S)=0$.

[image]